# How do I use custom roles/authorities in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

While migrating a legacy application to spring security I got the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_filterChainProxy': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_filterChainList': Cannot resolve reference to bean '_filterSecurityInterceptor' while setting bean property 'filters' with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_filterSecurityInterceptor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [superadmin]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
```

In the old application there are roles like "superadmin", "editor", "helpdesk" etc. But in all Spring Security examples I only see roles like "ROLE_" ("ROLE_ADMIN" etc). When I rename "superadmin" to "ROLE_ADMIN" and only use this role in the config, everything works.

Doesn't work:

```
 <http auto-config="true">                                      
    <intercept-url pattern="/restricted/**" access="superadmin"/>
    <form-login
        authentication-failure-url="/secure/loginAdmin.do?error=true"
        login-page="/secure/loginAdmin.do" />        
</http>
```

Works:

```
<http auto-config="true">                                      
    <intercept-url pattern="/restricted/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <form-login
        authentication-failure-url="/secure/loginAdmin.do?error=true"
        login-page="/secure/loginAdmin.do" />        
</http>
```

Is possible to use custom role names?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283870/acegi-security-how-do-i-add-another-grantedauthority-to-authentication-to-anonym) may help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are using the default configuration which expects that roles starts with the `"ROLE_"` prefix. You will have to add a custom security configuration and set `rolePrefix` to "";

http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-53485.html

Comment: can i have a ROLE_FOO or a ROLE_BAR or a ROLE_ANYTHING_I_WANT ? The link you provided is not addressing the issue, its just some guy saying "Unable to set RolePrefix for RoleVoter"

Comment: Yes, you can have any role you want. The link shows a configuration example and it may not help you but it was useful to D. Wroblewski. If you need more help just post a new question, a lot of people is ready to answer it.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a complete configuration using access expressions (link provided by @rodrigoap seems a little bit outdated):

```
<http
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        use-expressions="true">

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter"/>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value=""/>
            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also always using expression (by config `use-expressions="true"`) to ignore `ROLE_` prefix.

After reading Spring Security 3.1 source code, I found when `use-expressions="true"` :

For `<security:http >`:
`HttpConfigurationBuilder#createFilterSecurityInterceptor()` will regist `WebExpressionVoter` but not `RoleVoter`、`AuthenticatedVoter`;

For `<security:global-method-security >`:   `GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser#registerAccessManager()` will regist `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter` (conditionally), then always regist `RoleVoter`、`AuthenticatedVoter`, regist `Jsr250Voter` conditionally;

`PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter` will process `PreInvocationAttribute` （PreInvocationExpressionAttribute will be used as implementation） which is generated according `@PreAuthorize`. `PreInvocationExpressionAttribute#getAttribute()` always return null, so `RoleVoter`、`AuthenticatedVoter` do not vote it.

Answer (score 2):

Using *Spring Security 3.2*, this worked for me.

**Change Role Prefix:**

```
<beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="NEW_PREFIX_"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticatedVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>   

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:constructor-arg >
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="roleVoter"/>
            <beans:ref bean="authenticatedVoter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Depending on where you want to apply the Role Prefix it can be applied at the Security schema level or bean level.

```
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="true">
```

**Apply Role Prefix at Service Level:**

```
<beans:bean id="myService" class="com.security.test">
    <security:intercept-methods  access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <security:protect access="NEW_PREFIX_ADMIN"/>
    </security:intercept-methods>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might also help:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?96391-Spring-Security-Plug-in-ROLE_-prefix-mandatory

Bassically, it says you have to write in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
roleVoter(org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter) {
    rolePrefix = ''
}
```

It worked for me.