# a very simple spring security 3 example don't work?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

a very simple spring security 3 example that i found on the net give me a strage ecxeption in jboss!
ecxeption with log:

```
        01:04:19,150 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [10]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [USER_NORMAL]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [10]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [USER_NORMAL]
01:04:19,152 ERROR [[/SinaP]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [10]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [USER_NORMAL]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
01:04:19,152 ERROR [[/SinaP]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [10]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [USER_NORMAL]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [USER_NORMAL]
01:04:19,153 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
01:04:19,153 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/SinaP] startup failed due to previous errors
01:04:19,153 INFO  [[/SinaP]] Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
01:04:19,171 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/SinaP state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/jboss-IIIII/server/default/tmp/5c4o12-ydfhap-grdgg7xq-1-grdgglsf-9m/SinaP.war/ deployment failed
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/C:/jboss-IIIII/server/default/deploy/SinaP.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/jboss-IIIII/server/default/tmp/5c4o12-ydfhap-grdgg7xq-1-grdgglsf-9m/SinaP.war/ deployment failed
```

my web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>PersianJava</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>Home.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring security file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">




<security:authentication-manager>
<security:authentication-provider>
<security:password-encoder hash="md5"></security:password-encoder>
<security:user-service>
<security:user name="sina" password="2253857" authorities="USER_NORMAL"/>
</security:user-service>
</security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/WEB-INF/denied.jsp" >
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="USER_NORMAL"/>
</security:http>

</beans>
```

every bit of helps will make me greatfull

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986892/how-do-i-use-custom-roles-authorities-in-spring-security

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure but I think role names in Spring security must start with `ROLE_` prefix.

Comment: yes..i searched again and your answer is on the right track.thanks

Comment: Role prefix documented [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#authorityClass)

Answer (score 3):

You must set below code:

```
 <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.acegisecurity.vote.RoleVoter">
    <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
</bean>
```

and start your roles with `ROLE_` or any other that you define it to value tag