# Default roles in Spring Security 3.1

Tags: java, spring-security, default, roles

The Spring 3.1 Security `contact` example uses a couple of roles in its `applicationContext-security.xml`:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/hello.htm" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/switchuser.jsp" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_switch_user" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
```

Where are these IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_USER roles defined? Are these default roles create by Spring Security?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY** is defined in the [AuthenticatedVoter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.html) class.
The various **ROLE_xxxx** have no special meaning.

Spring Security by defaults suggests these roles because they are used in most applications.
However you are free to define and use custom roles (i.e. ROLE_SUPERMAN).
You just have to make sure that the `UserDetail` returned by your `UserDetailService` has this `ROLE` assigned as `GrantedAuthority` (either from a DB or manually).

Actually **ROLE** is the prefix.  If you want to change it to **APP** (i.e. APP_ADMIN) you have to define a custom `AppVoter`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.vote.RoleVoter">
  <property name="rolePrefix" value="APP"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: By user, I guess you mean UserDetail. And by UserService I guess you UserDetailService. And by role, I guess you mean GrantedAuthority. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

Roles `ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_USER` are defined by us according to our application.

How to create custom roles : [How do I use custom roles/authorities in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986892/how-do-i-use-custom-roles-authorities-in-spring-security)

Refer [Tutorial](http://giannisapi.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/spring-3-spring-security-implementing-custom-userdetails-with-hibernate/) to create custom roles using `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`