# Custom Auth User in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a custom authentication implementation outside of Spring Security which I am in the process of integrating.

I am generating a Spring User as part of the auth process based on my existing User model.

Everything seems to be working fine except for the getAuthority function.

I have the below in my User model which implements UserDetails.

```
  @Override
    public Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(this.role));
        return authorities;
    }
```

However, I am getting the below response.

> "message": "A granted authority textual representation is required",

I believe I am missing the generation of correct ROLES in my DB. Currently `private String role` is "USER".

**I think my question is this**.

What is the correct format for my role field to allow this to work correctly and what is the best way to insert this role?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

If you are using `Spring`'s default security configuration, a "*`ROLE_`*" prefix is needed.
Usually, the basic values are: `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`.

If not - check the custom configuration.

Related questions:

1. [Custom security configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986892/how-do-i-use-custom-roles-authorities-in-spring-security).
2. [Adding additional roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283870/acegi-security-how-do-i-add-another-grantedauthority-to-authentication-to-anony).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have modfied the DB for the prefix you suggested, however I still get the same response. I will review the links your sent.

Comment: You were right. I just realized I was still using a dummy User Object with no role. I just updated to pull from DB using your suggested prefix and it is now working. Thanks for your help.